# Regular expression to create xpath with Robot Framework

Tags: python, xpath, robotframework

I'm automating an application with the Robot Framework (Python 2.7). I use the xpath to locate the objects. I have seen that the xpath of the objects is different when I change the language application. For example:

ES

// * [@ id = "dnn_ctr**489**_ViewINT_Cupones_ibtnAdd"]

FR

// * [@ id = "dnn_ctr**644**_ViewINT_Cupones_ibtnAdd"]

EN

// * [@ id = "dnn_ctr**583**_ViewINT_Cupones_ibtnAdd"]

This forces me to redo the Test Case because the xpath is different.

Is it possible to use a regular expression to form the xpath? How can I avoid having to redo the test cases for each different language?

Thank you.
Marta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### XPath 1

xpath 1.x doesn't support wildcards or regular expressions. However, xpath supports several [string functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions) which can be combined to match what you want. For example, there's a `starts-with` function. There's no `ends-with`, but there is a `contains`, so you could use something like this:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'dnn_ctr') and contains(@id, 'ibtnAdd')]
```

Of course, that will match somethign like "dnn_ctr blah ibtnAdd blah". If you need precisely "starts with cnn_ctr" and "ends with ibtnAdd" you can do that with a little more work:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'dnn_ctr') and substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('ibtnAdd') + 1) = 'ibtnAdd' ]
```

### XPath 2

With xpath version 2 (which not all browsers support at the time I write this) you can use `ends-with`, making for a much more readable expression:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'dnn_ctr') and ends-with(@id, 'ibtnAdd')]
```

You can also match against a regular expression with `matches`:

```
//*[matches(@id, 'dnn_ctr.*ibtnAdd')]
```

Comment: Bryan Oakley, Thanks a lot. It has worked for me with the first option:

"//*[starts-with(@id, 'dnn_ctr') and contains(@id, 'ibtnAdd')]"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable file as input and put all your xpath values in it. I am using JSON in my example.Robot framework JSONlibrary can be used to parse JSON file (https://github.com/nottyo/robotframework-jsonlibrary)

**input.json**

```
{
    "Languages": {
         "ES": {
            "xpath1": "// * [@ id = "dnn_ctr489_ViewINT_Cupones_ibtnAdd"]",
             },
         "FR": {
            "xpath1": "// * [@ id = "dnn_ctr644_ViewINT_Cupones_ibtnAdd"]",
             },
         "EN": {
            "xpath1": "// * [@ id = "dnn_ctr583_ViewINT_Cupones_ibtnAdd"]",
             }
```

you can pass values to test cases based on your language selection in application by using a variable something like following

**test.py**

```
language_selected = 'EN'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed the JSON library but I do not know how to put your example into practice. Can you help me? How do I use the .json file?

Comment: What would be the motivation to create an object store in JSON when Robot Framework natively supports variable files in [Python](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files) or [YAML](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-file-as-yaml) format

Comment: @A.Kootstra That is a good point, It was just to show an example but Python dictionary can also be used instead of JSON format for input.